# SQL query to categorize time series data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like this:

```
ID   ScheduledPickUpTime   PickUpTime    ScheduledDropTime   DropTime
--  --------------------   ----------    -----------------   --------

1       00:10                 00:30         03:10             03:30
2       01:10                 02:10         03:05             03:10
3       02:30                 02:45         05:20             07:00
4       08:00                 08:45         13:00             14:00
5       11:20                 12:00         20:00             21:00
```

I need to display the information in the below format, with times spanning from 12 AM to 12 PM and each time field column counts in the time span.

```
TimeData               00:00-01:00   01:00-02:00  02:00-03:00  03:00-04:00  ....

ScheduledPickUpTime     1            1            1             0
PickUpTime              1            0            2             0
ScheduledDropTime       0            0            0             2
DropTime                0            0            0             2
```

I need help with creating the sql query which does this. Thanks in advance.

> Update:

The table has an additional EventType column. This column needs to be unpivoted and the counts for each EventType is based on the PickUpTime column

```
ID   ScheduledPickUpTime   PickUpTime    ScheduledDropTime   DropTime   EventType
--  --------------------   ----------    -----------------   --------

1       00:10                 00:30         03:10             03:30     Call
2       01:10                 02:10         03:05             03:10     Email
3       02:30                 02:45         05:20             07:00     Email  
4       08:00                 08:45         13:00             14:00     Call    
5       11:20                 12:00         20:00             21:00     Routine
```

The output in this case should be

```
TimeData               00:00-01:00   01:00-02:00  02:00-03:00  03:00-04:00  ....

ScheduledPickUpTime     1            1            1             0
PickUpTime              1            0            2             0
ScheduledDropTime       0            0            0             2
DropTime                0            0            0             2
Call                    1            0            0             0
Email                   0            0            2             0
Routine                 0            0            0             0
```

The values in the EventType column is dynamic and can have more such variations.

Is it possible to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Google "pivot table SQL"

Comment: I dont think its a straight forward "pivot"

Comment: Yes, it is, unless you want to dynamically generate the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather complicated.  It is a pivot and an unpivot:

```
select TimeData,
       sum(case when t >= '00:00' and t < '01:00' then 1 else 0 end) as [00:00-01:00],
       sum(case when t >= '01:00' and t < '02:00' then 1 else 0 end) as [01:00-02:00],
       sum(case when t >= '02:00' and t < '03:00' then 1 else 0 end) as [02:00-03:00],
       . . .
from t apply
     (values ('ScheduledPickUpTime', ScheduledPickUpTime, 1),
             ('PickUpTime', PickUpTime, 2),
             ('ScheduledDropTime', ScheduledDropTime, 3),
             ('DropTime', DropTime, 4)
     ) v(TimeData, t, ordering)
group by TimeData, ordering
order by ordering;
```

Comment: What does 't' refer to?

Comment: @vkr . . . Whatever the table name is.

Comment: can you take a look at the updated question and let me know if it is feasible? Thanks